# .net core 3.1: Endpoint routing for razor pages AND API controllers

Tags: c#, routes, upgrade, asp.net-core-3.1

**Edit - added query string

I have upgraded a Core 2.2 site to 3.1, and the only issue still bugging me is the following:  I have regular Razor pages and API controllers in the same application - shared code and functionality make this an easy solution.  In 2.2, there wasn't an issue with the following routing setup:

```
services.AddMvc()
```

and

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

in `Startup.ConfigureServices` and `Startup.Configure`, respectively.

My controller looks like:

```
{
    [Route("api/[controller][")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RRateController : ControllerBase
    {
        public RRateController()
        {
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<clsObject> Get([FromQuery] string[] TopCodes)
        {
            clsObject obj = new clsObject();
            ...
            return obj;
        }
}
```

The controller is called with the query string:

```
Root + '/API/RRate?TopCodes=Val1&TopCodes=Val2'
```

Upgrading to .net core 3.1, I am using

```
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddRazorPages();
```

and

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    };
```

in `ConfigureServices` and `Configure`.

My problem is that the string array for `TopCodes` is not passed into the controller.  The controller is accessed but the array is empty. A similar controller with no parameters works fine with the new setup.

How should I configure endpoints to work both with Razor pages with the Controller\Action\parameter pattern, and for the API controllers?

Comment: You should be able to use `AddMvc` in 3.1 still, but also could you post your query string?  Since you are attempting to pass the array via query string.

Comment: @Greg , using AddMvc caused other problems.  Added the query string to the question and here it is here too: `Root + '/API/RRate?TopCodes=Val1&TopCodes=Val2'`

Comment: Was the `[` in `api/[controller][` intentional? Shouldn't it be `api/[controller]`?

Comment: @Shoejep - you are absolutely right, and that was what was stoping the routing from working well.  Now I'm not sure if I should delete this question because there was no real problem, or keep it as a monument to typos.  Anyways - huge thank you for your sharp eyes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was the `[` in `api/[controller][` intentional? Shouldn't it be `api/[controller]`?